# White linear gradient defined in svg def , does't display white gradient. why ?

Tags: svg

I was just going though the MDN documention [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking) for clipping and masking in SVG and came across the following SVG::-

```html
    <svg width="200" height="200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="Gradient">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0" />
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="1" />
            </linearGradient>
            <mask id="Mask">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#Gradient)"  />
            </mask>
        </defs>
        
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="green" />
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="red" mask="url(#Mask)" />
    </svg>
```

I see the following two stop colors defined::-

```
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0" />
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="1" />
```

But when the `SVG` displays i see no white color, why is this ? looking at the above linear gradient, i would expect a white gradient instead of a red one, i am not quite understanding why there is no white gradient.

**NOTE** ::- this is a `why` question, not a `how-to-do-this-question`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient is not used to color the rectangle, but to define a mask. The `<mask>` is an offscreen image that is never shown, but only used to compute the element it is applied to.

In this case, the mask consists of a black (transparent) background, onto which a white gradient is added, so that it runs from black transparent to white opaque. When this mask is applied to the red rectangle, black is transformed into `opacity="0"`, and white is transformed into `opacity="1"`. So on the left, the lower green rectangle shines through, but on the right it doesn't and you see the red.

Comment: Now that is what you asked. In case you wondered: the coordinates I gave in the first attempt turn out to be the defaults. I should have looked...

Comment: thanks very insightful , so the  `stop-color="white"` does't really mean `fill:white` , but something like `reveal the fill color of the element this gradient is applied to`.

Comment: The formula is written out [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#feColorMatrixElement) under `luminaceToAlpha`. The resulting `A'` value is multiplied with the opacity of what the mask is applied to.